# Deploy Struts and Spring application using java service wrapper

Tags: java, windows

I am very new to Java Service Wrapper and windows service.

Can we run struts and spring application as windows service using Java Service Wrapper without any web server(Tomcat, Jboss etc.) ?.

Answer (score 0):

Java Service wrapper just allows you to run a Java application as a Windows service; however if you're using Struts, then you have a web application which needs to run on an app server such as JBoss or Tomcat.  So, short answer is: no.  You would use the JSW to start Tomcat as the service.